# Magento 2 How to remove what is paypal? text?

Tags: magento-2.1, paypal, paypal-standard

I'd like to remove what is paypal text and paypal logo from checkout.

I found it in
`vendor\magento\module-paypal\view\frontend\templates\payment\mark.pthml`

I tried comment out the codes but nothing has changed.
I flushed all caches and browser history.

Thank you

Comment: do you know how to change the hyperlink for "What is paypal?"

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to change files in vendor folder for many reasons!

You have to copy that file into your theme:

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Paypal/templates/payment/mark.phtml` and comment the code for showing this text.

Then execute `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and flush all caches to apply the changes

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer for Magento2 is to copy

`vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html`

to your Vendor/Theme/Magento_Paypal/web/template/payment folder and amend as required. Or other template file if using a different PayPal method.

If in developer mode, no need to (and shouldn't!) deploy static content. Just clear FPC if enabled.